# what can't be passed by vue slot props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

In official react docs, It says the difference between *'other libraries's slot'* and *'react's props.children'* is as follows :

> This approach may remind you of “slots” in other libraries but there are no limitations on what you can pass as props in React.
> https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

And it sounds like there are some things can't pass through a 'vue slot'. Is there any thing can't be passed by vue slot's props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue you have props as well. The difference and what may have been confusing you is that:

- (vue) props === (react) props
- (vue) slots === (react) props.children

You can pass data through props in both frameworks/libraries, but what you place inside `<YourComponent>[content]</YourComponent` will in vue terms be a slot and in react terms be accessible through props.children.

Let's say we have a popup/modal component which sole purpose is to act as a frame for the actual popup/modal content:

```
// parent component
<Modal>
    <p>Watch out! Do you want to continue</p>
    <button>Yes</button>
    <button>No</button>
</Modal>
```

Then you would have the modalcomponent itself

```
// react
<div>
    // this will output whatever you put inside the
    // <Modal> tags in you parent component
    {props.childen}
</div>

// vue
<div>
    // the <slot> tag works the same way
    // as React's {props.children}
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Read more about [vue slots here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#slot-content) and [vue props here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#props).

When you're more familiar with the concepts you can read about [vue's named slots here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#named-slots)